# Sails.js, application file not generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I'm new to Sails.js and are now working through some tutorials.

I have now created my Sails application and added a User model and controller. The application runs when executing sails lift. I am able the view the users and create more.

I cannot find the below referenced file that is supposed to contain basic application settings such as application name, port, environment and log level.

**config/application.js**

Am I missing something or did I create the application wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails have improved this setup. Now you should have an env folder under config with an environment config file. For example development.js

```
module.exports = {
   port: 1337
};
```

This will set the port for that environment. This environment is either set as the environment variable 'NODE_ENV' or you can specify this in your local.js file. Like so.

```
environment: development'
```

Note any variables set here can be accessed by using

```
sails.config.variable
```

So you can set up your own appname variable and access it like that.

Answer (score 2):

port and loglevel should be set in `config/env/[production|development]`

I think the name of the application is taken from the `package.json` if I'm not mistaken.